# We write but not on paper

Tags: riddle

> We write, but not on paper
>
> We draw, but not with ink
>
> We make things work
>
> But not in this realm
>
> We work in the webs

Hint I:

> Look between the webs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is about

> The internet/computers

And

> The 'we' are programmers

---

We write, but not on paper

> Programmers write code using a keyboard

We draw, but not with ink

> They can draw on tablets using fingers

We make things work
But not in this realm

> They can make programs, websites and the internet work, which are all online

We work in the webs

> World wide 'WEB'

Comment: But who on the internet?

Comment: @DaveRainbowin editted

Comment: Closer, but not on point! What about "We make things work"?

Comment: @DaveRainbowin tbh it could be a wide range of internet users. Engineers, coders, designers, architects etc. Id like to hazard a guess that it’s coders?

Comment: Programmers do help makes the internet work. So yes, it's the answer!

Comment: @DaveRainbowin thought so, corrected!